# Matrix theory: Solution of a system

Tags: matrices

$
A =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 7 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{array} } \right]
$

$
B =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 7 \\
3 & 2 & 9
\end{array} } \right]
$

if $
b =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3 
\end{array} } \right]
$ what condition must be $b_1, b_2, b_3$ satisfy in order that following system to be consistent?

(a): $Ax=b$ (b): $Bx=b$

Anyone can help me to solve this question?

Comment: Should (a) and (b) need to be satisfied simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. It needed to satisfy both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** A short answer is: $b$ should be a linear combination of vectors-columns of matrix $A$ and $b$ should be a linear combination of vectors-columns of matrix $B$.

Comment: How b is linear combination?

Comment: We can rewrite $Ax$ as $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 7 & 7 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{array} } \right] \cdot \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 
\end{array} } \right] = x_1\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 \\
3 \\
1 
\end{array} } \right]+x_2\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
2 \\
7 \\
1
\end{array} } \right]+x_3\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
3 \\
7 \\
3
\end{array} } \right]$.

Answer (score 1):

1) If the question is : Find the $b$ such that there exists $x$ and $y$ such that $Ax=b$ and $By=b$, this is equivalent to $b\in {\rm Im}(A)$ and $b\in {\rm Im}(B)$. As ${\rm det}(A)$ and ${\rm det}(B)$ are not zero, ${\rm Im}(A)={\rm Im}(B)=\mathbb{R}^3$, and there is no condition on $b$.

2) If the question is find the $b$ such that there exists an $x$ such that $Ax=Bx=b$, 
We see that $(A-B)x=0$. But ${\rm det}(A-B)$ is not zero; hence we must have $x=0$ and $b=0$